# Video Recording in an DSLR Camera

Tags: video, camera

Is there any Digital SLR Camera out there that supports video recording?
**Parameters:**

1. Only Nikon (Or may be Canon, in case there is a winnable alternative)
2. Entry Level (less than $700 or Rs.40,000)

Comment: Just curious, but why only Nikon? Pre-owned lenses and accessories?

Comment: Ya I have a couple from my other cam. Wanted to buy another one. Alright perhaps I can even do with Canon if there is an option.. :)

Comment: this question has nothing to do with computers, doesn't belong on superuser.com

Comment: Whats it not to do with computers?? Aren't Digital Cameras in close link with computers??

Comment: closer than a certain mp3 player that happens to be subject of many threads around here :)

Comment: @molly - sure does! I wonder what does the meaning of "super user" turn out into. If they want to confine it to simply computer and ONLY Computer related problems they might as well call it "noobstackoverflow.com" :) "super user" itself perhaps might convey the fact of operating over entire technological spectrum. Turning this into a much broader enterprise.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - I hope you are listening out there. Take a look at my just previous comment as a suggestion please. It might help you in increasing the expanse of this phenomena...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Nikon D5000](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00267S7TQ)**

12.3 MP DX Digital SLR, HD Video

Pirce: $700~

nice alternative to the very expensive D90.

the next 'smaller' model, D3000 doesn't feature video recording, so the D5000 is your best bet.

edit: if you don't mind Canon, then get the **[EOS 500D](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/CanonEOS500D/)**, the far better camera, pricing is similar to the Nikon D5000.

Answer (score 0):

The [Nikon D5000](http://www.nikonusa.com/Find-Your-Nikon/Product/Digital-SLR/25452/D5000.html) has what you might want, but it's a hair over $700 (it's $725 on the official Nikon site):

> Movie Modes
>
> - Movie with sound
> - Stop motion movie
> - D-Movie
> - HD 1280 x 720/24 fps VGA 640 x 424/24 fps QVGA 320 x 216/24 fps